# Spring Web MVC Project 404 error

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I just created a new project in eclipse. Here is the code.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd ">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <!--
    Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
    for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
    define an explicit mapping for it.
    -->

    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <!--
    The index controller.
    -->
    <bean name="indexController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />

</beans>
```

index.jsp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.0">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" 
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" session="false"/>
    <jsp:output doctype-root-element="html"
        doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
        omit-xml-declaration="true" />
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Insert title here
</body>
</html>
</jsp:root>
```

MainController.java

```
package SpringDemo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public ModelAndView loginWorld(ModelMap model) {

        return new ModelAndView("Main", "welcomeMessage","Hello Guest! welcome to out site");
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Insert title here
</body>
</html>
```

Project

[image]

In the above code, I am always getting `HTTP Status 404 - /SpringDemo/index` error when I try to run it via `http://localhost:8080/SpringDemo/index`

What is wrong with the code?

**EDIT**

Libraries used

```
aopalliance-1.0
commons-logging-1.1.2
commons-logging-1.2
hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final
jsch-0.1.49
jstl-api
jstl-impl
log4j-1.2.16
ojdbc6
slf4j-api-1.5.6
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.6
spring-aop-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-aop-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-aop-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-aspects-3.2.1.RELEASE
spring-aspects-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-aspects-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-aspects-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE
spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-beans-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-context-3.2.1.RELEASE
spring-context-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-context-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-context-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-context-support-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-context-support-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-context-support-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-core-3.2.1.RELEASE
spring-core-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-core-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-core-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-expression-3.2.1.RELEASE
spring-expression-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-expression-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-expression-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-instrument-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-instrument-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-instrument-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-instrument-tomcat-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-instrument-tomcat-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-instrument-tomcat-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-jdbc-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-jdbc-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-jdbc-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-jms-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-jms-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-jms-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-messaging-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-messaging-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-messaging-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-orm-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-orm-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-orm-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-oxm-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-oxm-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-oxm-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-test-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-test-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-test-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-tx-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-tx-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-tx-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-web-3.2.1.RELEASE
spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE
spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-webmvc-portlet-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-webmvc-portlet-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-webmvc-portlet-4.1.1.RELEASE
spring-websocket-4.1.1.RELEASE-javadoc
spring-websocket-4.1.1.RELEASE-sources
spring-websocket-4.1.1.RELEASE
validation-api-1.1.0.Final
```

Comment: @Abdelhak No, It should be `http://localhost:8080/index`

Comment: What errors do you get in the logs when you start up your application?

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava can you enable logs and then see if your context is being loaded at all. Are the request mappings being registered ? Is the XML file being loaded at all. Put in a debug point in the ContextLoader class and then check which location is being loaded in the "initWebApplicationContext" method there and start in debug mode. It is important to understand if the application is being loaded at all.

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava Try adding a leading `/` to `index.htm` - `<prop key="/index.htm">indexController</prop>`

Comment: You will need to create the necessary log configuration file set to 'debug' to see what is going on in the Spring MVC framework.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add to your file `dispatcher-servlet.xml` this:

```
  <mvc:annotation-driven />
```

This:

```
  <context:annotation-config/>
```

And this:

```
  <context:component-scan base-package="SpringDemo" />
```

And change the return ofthe method to a String like this:

```
  @RequestMapping("/index")
public String loginWorld(ModelMap model) {

    return "Main";
}
```

Comment: It was obviously missing but still the same issue? Finding hard to understand the problem!!

Comment: I tried `http://localhost:8080/SpringDemo/index` & `http://localhost:8080/SpringDemo/index.jsp`, its not working. It seems it cant even reach to the controller class. Is there any better debugging option so that I can find out where the problem is?

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava tryto add this : <context:annotation-config/>  to dispatcher-servlet.xml

Comment: Added this. Still not working. I think code is correct now but don't understand why it is not working.

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava try to post all your material I'll try to run it

Comment: Although I have put everything in the question above but still here is the link to the project `https://jumpshare.com/v/MmIP1ZndxWdJZzkF1CwB`

Answer (score 2):

Change `<load-on-startup>` element argument and try again.Also add `<context:component-scan>` for load your bean.I hope this will working for you.

Like :

```
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```